# Зачем нужны умные, мудрые и пр. указатели в С++

Tags: указатели, c++

1. Зачем нужны эти самые умные, мудрые и пр. типы 'указателей'?
2. В каких конкретно случаях нужно применять эти конкретные типы? В чем разница между ними?
3. Имеет ли смысл самому реализовать эти концепции на практике или использовать готовые варианты из boost? В чем преимущество этих вариантов?

Comment: <i>PS: я лично имел дело с 'умными указателями' и в целом даже, наверное, смогу сказать что это такое, но хотелось бы себя проконтролировать + нужно внятное, простое объяснение младшей сестре :-)</i>

Comment: На сколько младшей? Ну что бы знать какой ответ должен быть.
Или на кошечках объяснять или умными словами типа RAII.

Comment: -А что такое умные указатели? -Ээээ в компьютерных науках под умными указа... -Нууууу опять начялось, страшные слова, давай лучше про строение группы автоморфизмов конечных алгебр

Comment: Лучше с примерами. Кошечки, собачки - слишком примитивно. RAII - канает.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Благодаря умным указателям можно избежать утечек памяти и обеспечить безопасное ее использование.
2. Если честно, то нет таких ситуаций в которых не нужно было бы применять умных указателей. Вопрос скорее нужно поставить так - какой тип умного указателя нужно применить в той или иной ситуации?
3. Всегда нужно начинать с готовых классов, но бывают ситуации когда подцеплять к проекту столь громоздкую библиотеку, как boost просто невозможно по техническим причинам. В таких ситуациях выручает собственный класс, но нужно понимать что это будет скорее всего частный случай реализации умного указателя и конкурировать с библиотечным типом он сможет только в этом проекте.

Answer (score 8):

Приведу простой пример, для илюстрации необходимости умных указателей.
Вот такой участок кода:

```
A* a = new A();
B* b = new B();
C* c = new C();
doSomething(a, b, c);
delete a;
delete b;
delete c;
```

небезопасен, если конструкторы могут кидать исключения.
Безопасныйый код выглядит примерно так:

```
A* a = new A();
B* b;
try {
    b = new B();
} catch (...) {
    delete a;
    throw;
}
C* c;
try {
    c = new C();
} catch (...) {
    delete a;
    delete b;
    throw;
}
try {
    doSomething(a, b, c);
} catch (...) {
    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
    throw;
}
delete a;
delete b;
delete c;
```

что выглядит достаточно громоздко.
С использованием же умных указателей получится:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B());
std::unique_ptr<C> c(new C());
doSomething(a.get(), b.get(), c.get());
```

Comment: Пример некорректен до вызова doSomething(a, b, c). Поскольку, конструкторы не должны генерировать исключений. А если это случается, то обрабатывать совсем не так как у Вас приведено.

Comment: С каких пор конструкторы НЕ должны генерировать иссключения?? О_О

"А если это случается" - стоп, вы выше писали, что они НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ?!

Comment: IAZ, вы не путаете конструктор с деструктором?

Comment: Касательно конструкторов и исключений. См. <a href=http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/golub_cord.pdf>Аллена Голуба</href>, совет 161. Возбуждение исключений из конструктора ненадежно.

Comment: Посмотрел, это книга написана, когда исключения в C++ только появились. Сам автор пишет, что только некоторые компиляторы некорректно обрабатывают исключения в конструкторах. В данный момент бросать исключения из конструторов безопасно.

Comment: @gecube, @dzhioev нет не путаю. Не должны потому, что если будет сгенерировано исключение в производном классе, тогда деструкторы базовых классов вызваны не будут. При определенных условиях это не безопасно. А обрабатывать, нужно так:
<code>
A::A() {
try {
// тут конструирование
}
catch(...) {
// тут отлавливание всех исключений
}
}
</code>

Comment: В любой нормальной книжке написано, что деструктор у базового класса нужно делать виртуальным - в этом случае все нормально вызывается.
А ваше предложение плохое, т.к. в случае ошибки в конструкторе, получается невалидный объект и  приходится добавлять какой-то флажок для проверки того, валидный объект или нет

Answer (score 5):

Итак, получается, что умные указатели нужны, чтобы обойти ограничения, получаемые при использовании классических указателей C++.
Преимущества использования умных указателей:

1. Автоматическая инициализация.
2. Автоматическая очистка.
3. Отсутствие проблем с указателями на уже удаленные объекты.
4. Умные указатели - exception safe
5. С помощью умных указателей можно реализовать алгоритмы сборки мусора. Которые в С++ изначально отсутствуют.
6. Возможность повысить эффективность кода при наличии доп. информации об объектах, на которые необходимо ссылаться