# Умные указатели

Tags: c++

1. Обычные указатели ушли в прошлое? А то с выхода 11 стандарта прошло 5 лет, а везде до сих пор старая добрая `*`, из русско-язычной литературы видел их только у Мейерса.
2. В чем особенность каждого (с учетом 14 стандарта)?
3. Меня одного раздражает их длина `kappa`?
4. Это правда, что, вроде как, они позволяют избавиться от большого участка кода, очистки памяти (с исключениями и т. д.)? И, как следствия, повысить безопасность?
5. На сколько они затратны по памяти?

Comment: 4) Да. И не просто от нехилого, а ещё и сложного.

Comment: По-моему, на каждый из этих вопросов уже есть ответы на ruSO.

Comment: Ну будет тогда все вместе), любопытные как я, только выиграют от этого

Comment: Всё вместе, имхо, это довольно обширный ответ получится. P.S. и что такое `kappa`?

Comment: @alexolut [ссылка](https://www.google.ru/search?q=kappa&newwindow=1&espv=2&biw=1164&bih=563&tbm=isch&imgil=ZmWinmy6jUIkAM%253A%253BDWqKAW3LT4OkIM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.urbandictionary.com%25252Fdefine.php%25253Fterm%2525253DKappa&source=iu&pf=m&fir=ZmWinmy6jUIkAM%253A%252CDWqKAW3LT4OkIM%252C_&usg=__RPJF03w89p6GNxjJGRgAlIRTFMU%3D&ved=0ahUKEwis0MeU5YTOAhXEbZoKHQ9OCGYQyjcIKA&ei=QN-QV6ywLsTb6QSPnKGwBg#imgrc=ZmWinmy6jUIkAM%3A)

Comment: @alexolut Я так понимаю, что kappa - это сарказм

Comment: @alexolut эта [статья](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9552/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%a1?rq=1) немного устарела и не дает полного ответа на вопросы, обновить явно не помешает)

Comment: Мне тоже интересны ответы на эти вопросы! Присоединяюсь к топику!

Comment: Обычные указатели никуда не ушли. Для ситуаций, где управление памятью довольно тривиальное (без исключений, один владелец), я бы использовал сырые указатели. Для ситуаций, где владелец меняется, могут вылезти исключения или просто для динамического выделения внутри блока и последующего уничтожения, советую использовать `умные`.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500062/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-raw-pointers-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-c

Comment: Никаких «все вместе». Разбейте на отдельные вопросы. Абсолютно всем лень отвечать аж на пять вопросов кучей. На один из них, каждый, отвечающий найдётся.

Comment: `Обычные указатели ушли в прошлое` — нет, они стали рассматриваться как невладеющие (в отличие от владеющих `std::unique_ptr` и `std::shared_ptr`).